# Can we use tiny black holes which vaporise quickly for converting mass into energy?

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes

I really don't know anything about this topic. I even don't know whether a part of mass of the object will be lost from our universe as it falls in the tiny black hole. Please help me to get it's answer I can't get a proper answer on internet.

Comment: Can we use those tiny black created in particle accelerators for this purpose

Comment: “*black holes which vaporise*” - The Hawking radiation is an idea, not a fact. Physics is an experimental science. Until this radiation is observed, black holes don’t evaporate.

Comment: “*a part of mass of the object will be lost from our universe*” - Black holes are expected to obey the energy conservation law. No mass/energy should be lost from the universe when an object falls to a black hole.

Comment: If you "really don't know anything about this topic" then you won't understand the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In principle yes. However, there is a number of "practical" problems:

1. **We don't know how to create a tiny a black hole.** Despite some of the hype about the LHC potentially creating micro black holes, this has never happened (and was always an extremely long shot, based on known physics breaking down in a very specific way.)
2. **Keeping it alive.** The amount of Hawking radiation produced by a micro black is rather insane (and becomes bigger for smaller/lighter black holes). You would need to feed the black hole an equivalent amount of mass to keep it alive. You can play with the numbers [here](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator). For example, if you could get you hands on a micro black hole weighing 1 metric ton, you would need to feed it 3 million metric ton every second to keep it alive. Some how this would have to go into a black hole that is about a billionth the size of a proton.
3. **Storing it**. A more reasonably sized black hole say 100 nm (the wave length of UV light), would be absolutely massive, weighing nearly $10^{21}$ kg (about 1% of the moon). You would not be able to store this anywhere on Earth.

There is probably a bunch more, but I'm going to stop here.

Comment: Can't I make a tiny temporary black hole and quickly throw in mass for converting the mass into energy and store that energy and use it later for again creating a temporary black hole for generating energy whenever I need. Can't we use light from insanely powerful lasers to create tiny temporary black holes.

Comment: You can't throw mass in.  You can't get the mass anywhere near a tiny black hole. (also you can't make a tiny temporary black hole, the current generation of particle accelerators/lasers don't make them)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but...

We don't have any such black holes. It has been suggested that a particle accelerator could create some very tiny ones, but these would be no good.  We would need a black hole of the right size, to be small enough to radiate black body radiation at a useful rate, but not so small that would evaporate instantly.  It would also need to be moving slowly.  Particle accelerators could create black holes that evaporate after a nanosecond, and travel close to the speed of light. So we'd need a (say) mountain mass black hole.  This object is tiny! Smaller than an atom.

We have no technology for handling such an object. You can't put it in a building, it would fall through the floor. You'd probably need to get it into orbit. And then you have the problem of getting the power from space down to Earth.

It is surprisingly hard to feed such a black hole. Recall that it is very tiny.  It is also very hot. If you just put some matter near to it, the matter falls down goes and would go into an orbit, were it not for the intense Hawking radiation, which will push the matter away from the black hole.

So while it is true that a black hole does release the full mass energy of anything matter that falls into it, it is not a practical way of generating energy with current, or foreseeable technology.

Comment: I have a question, when some matter falls into a black hole does its all mass gets converted into energy or a part of its gets lost within the black hole.

Comment: In Hawking process, eventually all the mass is released, but towards the end of the evaporation, not only photons are emitted, but all particles, randomly.  At the end of the process there is no black hole.